# 'For now until the next year' or 'During now until the next year' or 'During the period of now until the next year?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

I want to tell something like;

> 'From the present moment until the next 1 year from now on'.

How do I say that in a more natural way / How usually a native speaker explains what I mean?

> 1: 'For now until the next year?'

> 2: 'During now until the next year?'

> 3: 'During the period of now until the next year?'

Comment: Welcome! Please give a complete sentence showing how you wish to use the phrase. We cannot answer unequivocally from a single isolated phrase. How would you use the phrase? To make an appointment? To state the length of time it will take to complete a project? These will require different answers.

Comment: Usually you won't need to include anything about "now" because that's assumed by using the present tense.  So the phrase "for the next year" or "through the next year" naturally includes the time period you are talking about.

Comment: Yes, to tell the length of time I will take to finish particular progress. How do I convey that? @chasly-supportsMonica

Comment: I still do not understand your question. As I said, please give a complete sentence as an example of how you wish to *use* the phrase. At the moment it is too general to be answerable.  Please give a specific example.